# Route in codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am learning codeigniter 3

In my config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/ci3x/admin/';
```

In my routes.php:

```
$route['customer'] = 'customer/index';
```

In controllers/customer.php:

```
class Customer extends MY_Controller{
    function index(){
    // some code here
    }
}
```

When I type: `http://localhost/ci3x/admin/customer` on brower, it back error 404.
I have no clue to fix, please help me to solve it.
Many thanks

Comment: typo in "funtion" should be "function"

Comment: sory, my false. But that not happend in my code :))

Comment: did you try http://localhost/ci3x/admin/customer/index and http://localhost/ci3x/admin/index.php/customer and http://localhost/ci3x/admin/index.php/customer/index

Comment: Have you overridden your index.php

Comment: @MichaelLWatson I try them all but nothing work.
I also have 
$route['default_controller'] = 'dashboard';
 and it work find with:  http://localhost/ci3x/admin/
so I don' think that is my problem
I have not changed file index.php yet.

Comment: In `.htaccss` file before any rules set `RewriteBase /ci3x/admin/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are extending a Class and that class does have a constructor, your class needs a constructor that also calls the constructor of the extended class.

Else things won't get up and running correctly.

```
class Customer extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); // Call the MY_Controller constructor
    }

    function index(){
    // some code here
    }
}
```

The same goes for your MY_Controller constructor as it will need to call CI_Controller constructor... It ripples down and everything gets initialised correctly (in simplistic terms) .

**Note:** 
Be careful with your controller and method files names. If you read the user guide it will say that the file names for controllers and methods should start with a capital letter.

So your `controllers/customer.php` should be `controllers/Customer.php`. If you are running on Windows it won't care. If you are running on Linux it will definitely matter.

Comment: Thanks, you save me :))